# Adding a slideshow to a webpage

Tags: web, slideshow, photo

I need help. Apologies if the information I provide is not sufficient. I'm sort of an all-arounder at this job and this task has been thrown at me.

I need to add a slideshow to a a webpage. I am not even sure what code I need: jQuery, CSS, or HTML.

The homepage of the website has a Nivio slider (can't access the code to this because its owned by a management company we can't afford to pay).

This is what the editing page looks like: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROAJv.png)

The website is http://evelyns-kitchen.com

I am looking to add something like the Nivio slider (if I can't actually add a Nivio slider). Smooth transition, clean, dots below photo to represent the image, left/right arrow. Let me know what other information I can provide! Thank you so much.

Comment: StackOverflow is used by programmers to help each other with coding problems, as you mentioned you don't have access to the source code I think your best option is you contact the management company about the issues you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Use **zoho reports** www.reports.zoho.com where you can create reports dashboards slideshows and many more